Cómo puedo hacer que se muestre estos datos a la tabla?
Anteriormente lograba registrar una mascota y a la hora de registrar mi mascota me creaba una carnet donde en ella podía ver sus detalles, después de moverle a algunas cosas del frontend ya no deja colocar detalles al registrar la mascota, solo se crea la mascota y su carnet pero los detalles no se registran.
Tambien me di cuenta que al agregar mas detalles a la carnet tampoco se muestran en su vista de carnet pero en la base de datos si existe.
Les dejo el codigo de las funciones en el controlador:
public function registrar_mascota() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre', 'Nombre mascota', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_especie', 'Especie'. 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_sexo', 'Sexo', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_raza', 'Raza', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('edad', 'Edad', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_obtencion', 'Modo de obtención', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('esterilizado', 'Esterilizado', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('rasgoUnico', 'Rasgo único');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('vet_oficial', 'Vbeterinaria');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nom_vet', 'Nombre veterinaria');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nom_clinica', 'Nombre clínica');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cedula', 'Cédula');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_dueno', 'Dueño', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('vac_rabia', 'Vacuna antirrabia');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('vac_parvovirus', 'Vacuna parvovirus');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desparasitada', 'Desparasitada');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fecha_registro', 'Fecha de registro');

    $data['especies'] = $this->MascotasModel->obtener_especies();
    $data['sexos'] = $this->MascotasModel->obtener_sexo();
    $data['razas'] = $this->MascotasModel->obtener_razas();
    $data['modos_obtencion'] = $this->MascotasModel->obtener_obtencion();
    $data['veterinarias'] = $this->MascotasModel->obtener_vets();
    $data['seguimientos'] = $this->MascotasModel->obtener_seguimiento();
    $data['duenos'] = $this->MascotasModel->obtener_duenos();


    // Verificar si la validación falla
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        // Cargar la vista pasando el array $data con los estatus
        $this->load->view('mascotas/registerpet.php', $data);
    } else {
        // Guardar el carnet si pasa la validación
        $data_mascota = array(
            'nombre' => $this->input->post('nombre'),
            'foto_mascota' => $this->input->post('foto_mascota'),
            'id_especie' => $this->input->post('especie'),
            'id_sexo' => $this->input->post('id_sexo'),
            'id_raza' => $this->input->post('id_raza'),
            'edad' => $this->input->post('edad'),
            'id_obtencion' => $this->input->post('id_obtencion'),
            'esterilizado' => $this->input->post('esterilizado'),
            'rasgoUnico' => $this->input->post('rasgoUnico'),
            'vet_oficial' => $this->input->post('vet_oficial'),
            'nom_vet' => $this->input->post('nom_vet'),
            'nom_clinica' => $this->input->post('nom_clinica'),
            'cedula' => $this->input->post('cedula'),
            'id_dueno' => $this->input->post('id_dueno'),
            'vac_rabia' => $this->input->post('vac_rabia'),
            'vac_parvovirus' => $this->input->post('vac_parvovirus'),
            'desparasitada' => $this->input->post('desparasitada'),
            'fecha_registro' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')  // Capturar la fecha y hora actual
        );

        // Guardar la mascota en la base de datos
        $id_mascota = $this->MascotasModel->insertar_mascota($data_mascota);

        if ($id_mascota) {
            // 2. Crear el carnet para la mascota
            $data_carnet = array(
                'id_mascota' => $id_mascota,  // Relacionar el carnet con la mascota
                'estatus' => '1'
            );

            $id_carnet = $this->MascotasModel->insertar_carnet($data_carnet);

            if ($id_carnet) {
                // 3. Guardar los detalles del carnet
                $seguimientos = $this->input->post('seguimiento');
                $medicamentos = $this->input->post('nombre_medicamento');
                $fechas_seguimiento = $this->input->post('fecha_seguimiento');
                $observaciones = $this->input->post('observaciones');

                // Recorrer los detalles del carnet
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($seguimientos); $i++) {
                    if (!empty($seguimientos[$i])) {  // Verificar que el seguimiento no esté vacío
                        $data_detalle = array(
                            'id_carnet' => $id_carnet,  // Relacionar con el carnet
                            'id_tipo_medicamento' => $seguimientos[$i],
                            'nombre_medicamento' => $medicamentos[$i],
                            'fecha_detalle' => $fechas_seguimiento[$i],
                            'observaciones' => $observaciones[$i]
                        );
                        var_dump($data_detalle);  // Verificar los datos del detalle
                        
                        // Guardar cada detalle en la base de datos
                        $this->MascotasModel->insertar_detalles_carnet($data_detalle);
                    }
                }

                // Redirigir a una página de éxito
                redirect('mascotas/success');
            } else {
                // Manejar error al crear el carnet
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error al crear el carnet.');
                redirect('mascotas/registerpet.php');
            }
        } else {
            // Manejar error al crear la mascota
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Error al registrar la mascota.');
            redirect('mascotas/registerpet.php');
        }
    }
}

public function ver_carnet($id_mascota){

    $this->load->model('MascotasModel');
    $carnet = $this->MascotasModel->get_carnet_by_mascota($id_mascota);

    if ($carnet) {
        // Obtener detalles del carnet
        $detalles = $this->MascotasModel->get_detalles_by_carnet($carnet['id_carnet']);
        $carnet['detalles'] = $detalles;
    }

    // Pasar los datos a la vista
    $data['mascota'] = $carnet;
    $this->load->view('carnet/viewcarnet', $data);
}

public function agregar_detalles_carnet($id_carnet){

    $this->load->model('MascotasModel');

    // Reglas de validación
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('seguimiento[]', 'Seguimiento', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre_medicamento[]', 'Nombre de Medicamento', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fecha_seguimiento[]', 'Fecha de Seguimiento', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('observaciones[]', 'Observaciones', 'required');

    $data['seguimientos'] = $this->MascotasModel->obtener_seguimiento();
    $data['id_carnet'] = $id_carnet;
    

    // Si la validación falla, se muestra el formulario con los errores
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('carnet/detailscarnet', $data);
    } else {
        // Recoger los datos del formulario
        $id_carnet = $this->input->post('id_carnet');  // Suponiendo que el carnet viene de un campo oculto
        $seguimientos = $this->input->post('seguimiento');
        $medicamentos = $this->input->post('nombre_medicamento');
        $fechas = $this->input->post('fecha_seguimiento');
        $observaciones = $this->input->post('observaciones');

        // Recorrer los arrays y guardar los detalles
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($seguimientos); $i++) {
            $detalle = array(
                'id_carnet' => $id_carnet,
                'id_tipo_seguimiento' => $seguimientos[$i],
                'nombre_medicamento' => $medicamentos[$i],
                'fecha_detalle' => $fechas[$i],
                'observaciones' => $observaciones[$i]
            );

            // Insertar cada detalle en la base de datos
            $this->MascotasModel->insertar_detalles_carnet($detalle);
        }

        // Redireccionar o mostrar mensaje de éxito
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Detalles agregados correctamente.');
        redirect('index.php/mascotas/view_carnet/' . $id_carnet);
    }
}'''

Tambien de las funciones en el modelo:
public function get_carnet_by_mascota($id_mascota) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('t_mascotas_carnet');
    $this->db->where('id_mascota', $id_mascota);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    
    return $query->row_array(); 
}

// Metodo para obtener detalles de una carnet
public function get_detalles_by_carnet($id_carnet) {
    $this->db->where('id_carnet', $id_carnet);
    $query = $this->db->get('t_mascotas_carnet_detalles');  
    return $query->result_array(); 
}

public function get_carnet_by_id($id_carnet) {
    $this->db->where('id_carnet', $id_carnet);
    $query = $this->db->get('t_mascotas_carnet');
    return $query->result_array();
}

// Metodo para obtener razas por especie
public function obtener_razas_por_especie($id_especie) {
    $this->db->where('id_especie', $id_especie);
    $query = $this->db->get('cat_razas');
    return $query->result_array();
}

// REGISTRO DE MASCOTAS 

public function insertar_mascota($data){
    $this->db->insert('t_mascotas', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id(); 
}

public function insertar_carnet($data){
    $this->db->insert('t_mascotas_carnet', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id(); 
}

public function insertar_detalles_carnet($data_detalle){
   log_message('debug', 'Insertando detalle carnet: ' . print_r($data_detalle, true));
   return $this->db->insert('t_mascotas_carnet_detalles', $data_detalle);
}

public function obtener_detalle_por_id($id_detalle) {
    $this->db->where('id_detalle', $id_detalle);
    return $this->db->get('t_mascotas_carnet_detalles')->row_array();
}

public function actualizar_detalle_carnet($id_detalle, $datos) {
    $this->db->where('id_detalle', $id_detalle);
    return $this->db->update('t_mascotas_carnet_detalles', $datos);
}    

public function eliminar_detalle_carnet($id_detalle) {
    $this->db->where('id_detalle', $id_detalle);
    return $this->db->delete('t_mascotas_carnet_detalles');
}    

Las tecnologías que utilizo son Codeigniter 3 y HeidiSQL
Es mi primera vez haciendo una pregunta en stackoverflow, asi que espero que entiendan lo que les comparto y me puedan ayudar :s
Muchas gracias
